# Benefits or otherwise of naming workgroup same as domain?

Tags: windows, domain, workgroup

We have a small office network consisting of a windows domain server and 5 desktop machines joined to the domain.
We now have another desktop pc to connect to the network, but as it is running Windows 7 Home it cannot join the domain.

I have the option of changing the workgroup name to something else.  If I change it to COMPANYDOMAIN or COMPANYDOMAIN.local, would that have any effect on anything at all such as making it easier to access resources?

Comment: `Benefits or otherwise of naming workgroup same as domain?` - None.

Comment: Why would you not simply upgrade to 10 pro and just join it?

Comment: @JimB, purely out of cost and time at the moment.  May do that later.

Comment: @usersteve Unless you're paid in bottle caps, your going to end up spending more time/money fooling around with permission issues than you'd pay for a full price version of 10.